# (|) vertical bar & (<) smaller then is not registering on Ubuntu server, instead it is showing (>) greater then symbol?

Tags: server, 18.04

**(|)** vertical bar & **(<)** smaller then is not registering on Ubuntu 18.04.03 server, instead it is showing **(>)** greater then symbol?

[image: Ubuntu server image showing (>)]

I have tried copy/paste also from "Notepad" or typing keys using virtual keyboard. But it is only registering (>) greater then symbol. Any solution please?